# Idiomatic phrase - tangled in my foot

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

> Cables used to get tangled in my foot.

is **tangled in my foot** idiomatic? If not, what's the better way?

Comment: "Tangled around my foot", or "tangled up around my foot", or perhaps even better "wrapped around my foot". Just think about the preposition carefully. "In a foot" seems pretty unlikely.

Comment: Your feet used to get tangled in cables, rather than the other way round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Tangled around my foot"

or

> tangled up around my foot",

or perhaps even better

> "wrapped around my foot".

Just think about the preposition carefully. "In a foot" seems pretty unlikely.

As a general word of advice here, cables "tangle themselves up", and you become "wrapped up in the cable".

One last possibility:

> My foot got [entangled](http://thefreedictionary.com/entangle) in the cables.